# Where should I include MetaData file whether in web.config or else where in code?

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml, ping

I'm very new to SSO(Single Sign On) using SAML i have a lot of confusion regarding this SSO login integration. Identity Provider gave me a MetaData file to include in my project but i don't know where to include it and how to use it. Please help me  with any proper documentation which you have used before and give me some brief idea about integration process.

Comment: You should not use metadata file directly which is not recommended at the moment because of public key rolling, instead, you should get metadata information directly from metadata URL

Comment: Hi @cuongle will you please help me with any working document for better understanding about SSO SAML?

Comment: Look at step 2.4.4 here - https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/saml2/latest/saml2.pdf Does your IDP have a metadata URL? i.e. metadata available online. Then Sustainsys will figure it out for you!

Answer (score 1):

What client-side software are you using?

What SAML stack does the client use?

Some stacks allow you to import the metadata and then it makes the changes.

Otherwise, you have to look at the metadata and then copy the relevant pieces over.

e.g. there will be a place to configure entityID and Assertion Consumer Service.

You need to look through the metadata and copy them over.

The metadata itself is not included in the project.

Comment: We are using Sustainsys/Saml2 . I have MetaData file but i don't have idea where to configure it, that is what i'm asking you to help.